# how to wire 2 pole 240 v contactor/120v coil

Tags: wiring

I would like to see a simple example of how to wire in the float switch and coil. This is a [Diversitech 30 amp contactor](https://www.diversitech.com/en-US/item/id/15504) EC302120.

Comment: I am unable to find either a diagram of the terminals or a clear photograph of the markings on the top of the unit. Can you please either link to such on the web or attach a clear photograph of the top?

Answer (score 1):

### Whoops, you blew it.

Having done a very similar thing with a timer for a hot water heater, you hoisted yourself by your own petard by buying a 120V coil.

There is nowhere to obtain 120V on your 240V device.   There is only Hot L1 and Hot L2 present.  To get 120V, there'd need to be a neutral wire there.  It's just not there.  (and no, you can't bootleg ground).

You need a 240V-coil contactor for this.   Or, if that's a problem for the float switch, then get 24 volt low voltage from the furnace or doorbell transformer, and use a 24V-coil contactor.

Comment: perhaps he could use a step-down transformer to provide a 120V supply for the contactor